# Will functions called from PHP while loop finish before next loop starts?

Tags: php

I am looping through database row results, creating a PDF with the createPDF function below which in turn calls an email function. I am trying to understand whether these processes will run synchronously (waiting for each function to finish before the next loop begins), or whether I am creating a situation where too many processes end up running at once (exceeding memory limit etc.) if the there are many rows to process.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    global $firstname;
    $firstname = $row["first"];
    global $email;
    $email = $row["email"];
    createPDF(); // Calls function to send PDF by email when completed
}
```

What is the best practice for this scenario?

Comment: Yes.  PHP is synchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how PDF creation looks like. If it forks an external process without waiting for it to finish - then yes, you may have many processes running in parallel and overloading the system.

Comment: createPDF() uses FPDF which is included in the same page...not sure what the definition of "external process" is technically?

Comment: FPDF is implemented in pure PHP and will not create external processes - so yes, the loop will be processes synchronously